# How do I get the url for a model?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-urls

Given the following situation:

```py
# models.py
class Book(Model):
    pass

# views.py
class BookDetail(DetailView):
    model = Book


# books/urls.py
urlpatterns += [path('detail/<int:pk>', BookDetail.as_view(), 'book_detail')]

# page/urls.py
urlpatterns += [path('books/', include('books.urls'))]
```

I can load the detail view for the object with the private key id 42 at `/books/detail/42/`. If I am in another request with a completely different path and hold a reference to the object with the private key id 42, is there an "official" or builtin way to generate the url `/books/detail/42/`? Preferably outside of templating, so I can respond with a JSON.

Or is the idiomatic way to parametrize the path elements (`books` and `detail`) and just rebuild it myself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes**, you can make use of `get_absolute_url` for model-specific views and the `{% url ... %}` template tag to calculate the name of a view.

## Model-specific views

If a `Model` has a *specific* view to show details, you can implement a [**`get_absolute_url`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#get-absolute-url) on your model, like:

```
from django.urls import reverse

class Book(Model):

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('book_detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

Here we use [**`reverse`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/urlresolvers/#django.urls.reverse) to "calculate" the URL for the given name of the view (specified in your `path(..., name='book_detail')`) with as `pk` parameter, the `pk` of `self`.

In your template you can then write:

```
<a href="{{ my_object.get_absolute_url }}">{{ my_object }}</a>
```

with `my_object` the name of the variable in your template.

It is note that the [**`redirect`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect) function understands the `get_absolute_url`, and thus you can write `return redirect(my_object)` in a view, and it will automatically call `get_absolute_url` to redirect to the proper view.

If you serialize a model with the Django REST framework, then you can reuse the `get_absolute_url` as well, by using a [**`URLField`** [drf-doc]](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#urlfield) for example:

```
from rest_framework.serializers import ModelSerializer, URLField

class BookSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    absolute_url = serializers.URLField(
        read_only=True,
        source='get_absolute_url'
    )
```

This specific use case is documented in the documentation of the Django REST framework.

## Making use of `{% url ...%}` in the template

You can also calculate the URL of a view, by using the [**`{% url ... %}`** template tag [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#url). You can for example write:

```
<a href="{% url 'book_detail' pk=my_object.pk %}">{{ my_object }}</a>
```

to calculate the URL, just like we did with the `get_absolute_url`. It is however useful as well for other, non model-specific views.